# Loss eth0 after update

Tags: networking

I lost eth0 after the last update. Output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID="elementary OS"
DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.2.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=luna
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS Luna"
```

Output of `uname -r

```
3.2.0-91-generic
```

Output of `ifconfig`

```
lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:1715 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:179306 (179.3 KB) Octets transmis:179306 (179.3 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:12:b3:89:5a:49  
          inet adr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::3210:b3ff:fe69:5a49/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:5472 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5341 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:3705285 (3.7 MB) Octets transmis:895453 (895.4 KB)
```

Where's `eth0`???

Comment: You appear to be using elementary Luna. The only updates you will be receiving will be from upstream Ubuntu repositories. It is unlikely there will be many answer forthcoming for this other than "Upgrade to Freya".

Comment: The Question is about a release or feature that has been significantly updated, to the point at which upgrading fixes the issue or answers the question.